# Distribute tensorflow : supervisor not initializing?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert the MNIST tensorflow [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py) to run in distributed form. I am using the template given on the documentation [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html), to do so.  Here is my code :

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")

# Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


# Import data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


def main(_):
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

  # Create and start a server for the local task.
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                           job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                           task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

  if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
  elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

      # Build model...
      #loss = ...
      #global_step = tf.Variable(0)


      # Create the model
      x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
      W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
      b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
      y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

      global_step = tf.Variable(0)

      #train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
      #    loss, global_step=global_step)

      # Define loss and optimizer
      y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
      cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
      train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy,global_step=global_step)



      saver = tf.train.Saver()
      summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
      init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

    # Create a "supervisor", which oversees the training process.
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                             logdir="/tmp/train_logs",
                             init_op=init_op,
                             summary_op=summary_op,
                             saver=saver,
                             global_step=global_step,
                             save_model_secs=600)

    # The supervisor takes care of session initialization, restoring from
    # a checkpoint, and closing when done or an error occurs.
    with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
      # Loop until the supervisor shuts down or 1000000 steps have completed.
      step = 0
      while not sv.should_stop() and step < 10000:
        # Run a training step asynchronously.
        # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
        # perform *synchronous* training.
        #_, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step])
        print(step)
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        train_feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}
        _, step = sess.run([train_step, global_step],feed_dict = train_feed)


    # Ask for all the services to stop.
    sv.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

First, I start 2 parameter servers and then 2 worker nodes. The servers get initialized properly in all 4, but the supervisor doesn't start training.

Here is supervisor output :

```
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {url1:2220, url1:2221}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:206] Initialize HostPortsGrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {localhost:2230, url2:2230}
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:202] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2230

Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before. Here are two pieces of advice for you. First, you should make sure the nodes are communicating with each other. Second, you should check your version of Tensorflow. I had this problem on v12 but the same code worked fine on v10.